# Php: concat constants in a variable

Tags: php

```
class MyClass
{
    const EVENT_NAME='Name of the event';

    const EVENT_DATE='xx/xx/xxxx';

    public $eventName = self::EVENT_NAME.' '.self::EVENT_DATE;
}
```

Doesn't work!
I want to have the concatenation of 2 constants in a variable.

Comment: You can't define class properties that are the result of evaluations, and concatenation is an evaluation

Comment: You need to do that in the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MyClass
{
    const EVENT_NAME='Name of the event';

    const EVENT_DATE='xx/xx/xxxx';

    public function __construct() {
        $this->eventName = self::EVENT_NAME.' '.self::EVENT_DATE;
    }

    public $eventName;
}
```

Comment: The solution works. But I occurred some problem with Yii framework and the method : isNewRecord(). The method always return is not a new record, because I override the method __construct! So I use the method init() instead of __construct with Yii framework.